# AMP URL query string issues

Tags: amp-html

Hi I've set up AMP on one of our sites using a query string on the end of the URL (?amp=1). We have over 100 pages indexed in web master tools but we yet to see any of our posts in the search results.

Now here’s the issue. We found the AMP URL that Google uses to serve AMP pages and used one of our AMP pages to test in the emulator:

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/www.thefca.co.uk/news/the-big-sing-off-2016/?amp=1

As you can see it says the page isn’t valid even though the pages is valid according to the Chrome plugin and the ?development=1 method. However looking closely this page is actually removing the query string at the end so Google is trying to validate the NON AMP page. Which is why we are getting errors. (We figured this out by clicking debug original page.)

So to test this we changed the URL structure so the AMP pages work without needing a query string.

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/www.thefca.co.uk/amp/news/14361/the-big-sing-off-2016/

This time it pulls the AMP page. No errors and we see the page.

Looking at the documentation I can’t see any official requirements for the URL structure and I'm sure the Wordpress plugin uses this structure, which is where we got the idea.

Is this a bug or are we jumping ahead of ourselves by going direct to the Google AMP URL? The big question is whether this affecting us in the search results and other users if the pages are being returned as valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were getting ahead of ourselves on this. Google confirmed they will deal with the query string when they index the page. We still changed the URL structure just to rule this issue out. We're still yet to see any of our pages in the AMP results though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your mapping between the canonical and the AMP is broken.

Your canonical has:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.thefca.co.uk/amp/news/14361/the-big-sing-off-2016" />
```

but it should have:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.thefca.co.uk/news/the-big-sing-off-2016/?amp=1" />
```

Comment: We changed the URL of the AMP pages in the end to rule out a query string error. So this canonical link is correct. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use  https://www.google.co.uk/amp/... ?
Do you want test the [cache](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/using_the_google_amp_cache/) ?
I use url parameter [html-amp=1](http://www.usa-reisetipps.net/?html-amp=1) on all my sites without any problems. Google have no url rules, he is looking at the:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.usa-reisetipps.net/?html-amp=1" />
```

and vis-a-vis.